# How to debug exec script for collectd

Tags: bash, debugging, debian, exec, collectd

I wrote a little script to collect the power state (standby, actice) of my disk.
It is based on this script: https://github.com/collectd/collectd/blob/master/contrib/exec-smartctl

`/usr/share/collectd/exec_hddpwrmode.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTNAME="${COLLECTD_HOSTNAME:-$(hostname -f)}"
INTERVAL="${COLLECTD_INTERVAL:-60}"

while sleep "$INTERVAL"
do
  for disk in sda sdb sdc sdd sde sdf
  do
    STATE=$(sudo smartctl -i -n standby /dev/$disk | grep -e "Device is in STANDBY mode" -e "Power mode is:    ACTIVE or IDLE" 2>/dev/null)
    if [ "$STATE" = "Device is in STANDBY mode, exit(2)" ]
      then
        # STANBY
        VALUE="0"
      else
        if [ "$STATE" = "Power mode is:    ACTIVE or IDLE" ]
          then
            # ACTIVE or IDLE
            VALUE="1"
          else
            # ERROR
            VALUE="U"
        fi
    fi
    echo "PUTVAL $HOSTNAME/disk-$disk/disk-state interval=$INTERVAL N:$VALUE" | tee -a /tmp/hddpwrstate.log
  done
done
```

The output in `/tmp/hddpwrstate.log`looks good.

```
PUTVAL magneto/exec-smart/pwrstate_sdf interval=10.000 N:0
PUTVAL magneto/exec-smart/pwrstate_sda interval=10.000 N:0
PUTVAL magneto/exec-smart/pwrstate_sdb interval=10.000 N:1
PUTVAL magneto/exec-smart/pwrstate_sdc interval=10.000 N:0
PUTVAL magneto/exec-smart/pwrstate_sdd interval=10.000 N:0
PUTVAL magneto/exec-smart/pwrstate_sde interval=10.000 N:0
PUTVAL magneto/exec-smart/pwrstate_sdf interval=10.000 N:0
```

That means I have no permission issue (the script needs to be run by a user that can use sudo).
And it is executed by collectd

But I get no new rrd-files in `/var/lib/collectd/rrd/<hostname>` or new measurements in my InfluxDB.

```
> show measurements
name: measurements
name
----
cpu_value
df_value
disk_io_time
disk_read
disk_value
disk_weighted_io_time
disk_write
entropy_value
interface_rx
interface_tx
irq_value
load_longterm
load_midterm
load_shortterm
memory_value
processes_value
rrdcached_value
swap_value
uptime_value
users_value
```

I tried activating debug.

```
<Plugin syslog>
  LogLevel debug
</Plugin>
```

But it does not help.

```
Nov 19 12:13:12 magneto collectd[30028]: Exiting normally.
Nov 19 12:13:12 magneto collectd[30028]: collectd: Stopping 5 read threads.
Nov 19 12:13:12 magneto collectd[30028]: exec plugin: Sent SIGTERM to 30042
Nov 19 12:13:12 magneto collectd[30028]: collectd: Stopping 5 write threads.
Nov 19 12:13:13 magneto collectd[31752]: Stopping statistics collection and monitoring daemon: collectd.
Nov 19 12:13:13 magneto collectd[31767]: syslog: invalid loglevel [debug] defaulting to 'info'
Nov 19 12:13:13 magneto collectd[31768]: syslog: invalid loglevel [debug] defaulting to 'info'
Nov 19 12:13:13 magneto collectd[31769]: Initialization complete, entering read-loop.
Nov 19 12:13:13 magneto collectd[31764]: Starting statistics collection and monitoring daemon: collectd.
```

So, why does my script not work?
Is there something wrong?
Or how can I debug to find the issue myself?

My system: Debian 8 with OpenMediaVault.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that site.
No issues left in the script now.

But it is still not working with collectd.

Answer (score 4):

I got it working.

Loks like my PUTVAL was not correct.

This is working now:

```
echo "PUTVAL $HOSTNAME/exec-$disk/gauge-disk_state interval=$INTERVAL N:$VALUE" | tee -a /tmp/hddpwrstate.log
```

Comment: so it was about setting `exec-` as `plugin-instance` part of identifier and `guage-disk_state` as `type-instance` per documentation here: https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd-exec.5.shtml ?